# PHP Image Merge with Photo Frame

Tags: php, gd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I merge 3 images into 1 image via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419383/how-can-i-merge-3-images-into-1-image-via-php)

How do I merge a frame and a photo into specific location on the frame? I have the following code but it just do weird such that the photo has to be as big as the frame in order to merge them. Any solution aside or mistakes perhaps from what I have done? Much appreciate for all the responses.

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($me);

$frame = imagecreatefrompng('HorizontalFrame.png');



imagealphablending($frame, true);

imagesavealpha($frame, true);

imagecopy($image, $frame, 0, 0, 0, 0, 325, 276);

imagepng($image, 'image_4.png');
```

Comment: I think you should further research how imagecopy() works http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php

Comment: Hi Scuzzy, any recommended way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the correct way with better understanding:

> ```
> $images = array( $_GET['color'], $_GET['face'], $_GET['hat'] );
>
>     // Allocate new image
>     $img = imagecreatetruecolor(58, 75);
>     // Make alpha channels work
>     imagealphablending($img, true);
>     imagesavealpha($img, true);
>
>     foreach($images as $fn) {
>         // Load image
>         $cur = imagecreatefrompng($fn);
>         imagealphablending($cur, true);
>         imagesavealpha($cur, true);
>
>         // Copy over image
>         imagecopy($img, $cur, 0, 0, 0, 0, 58, 75);
>
>         // Free memory
>         imagedestroy($cur);
>     }   
>
>     header('Content-Type: image/png');  // Comment out this line to see PHP errors
>     imagepng($img);
> ```

Credited to: DMin via
[How can I merge 3 images into 1 image via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419383/how-can-i-merge-3-images-into-1-image-via-php)

Answer (score 1):

I use CSS:

- Just give the HTML an ID (ex. Char, hair,weapons)
- Then use value: absolute and map it on a specific x and y axis.

Image a will overlap image b

If your using PNG then you can set invisible NH which makes it more like a cooler one