# How to merge multiple images and text into single image?

Tags: php, image, php-gd

I have multiple PNG images inside a div, those images are PNG and presents as single image for user depending on custom options he/she has selected. Also, adding text is also enabled as other feature, which allows a div with texts to add above of those images.

Now i want to generate a image with those multiple images and text combined, maintaining the font-family & size of text.

For eg. the image that appears on interface with combination of images and text. (It's managed to appear with css positioning)
[image]
Where as this is made of two images below and text

[image: ![enter image description here]
[image]

This is what i tried taking images : create-image.php file

```
<?php
createimageinstantly();
function createimageinstantly($img1='',$img2='',$img3=''){
    $x=$y=1000;
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    $targetFolder = '/gw/media/uploads/processed/';
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;

    $img1 = $targetPath.'img1.png';
    $img2 = $targetPath.'img2.png';
    $img3 = $targetPath.'img3.png';

    $outputImage = imagecreatetruecolor(1000, 1000);

    $first = imagecreatefrompng($img1);
    $second = imagecreatefrompng($img2);
    $third = imagecreatefrompng($img3);

    imagecopy($outputImage,$first,0,0,0,0, $x, $y);
    imagecopy($outputImage,$second,0,0,0,0, $x, $y);
    imagecopy($outputImage,$third,0,200,-200,0, $x, $y);

    imagepng($outputImage, $targetPath .round(microtime(true) * 1000).'.png');

    imagedestroy($outputImage);
 }
?>
```

But this gives me whole black colored image
[image: ![enter image description here]

Also, i need to mix with text on the finally generated image

*edited* :

- jpg images changed to png
- `imagecopymege` changed to `imagecopy`

**Latest result :**

```
       <?php
            createimageinstantly();
            //$targetFolder = '/gw/media/uploads/processed/';
            //$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
            //$img3 = $targetPath.'img3.png';
            //print_r(getimagesize('http://www.vapor-rage.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/sample.jpg'));
            function createimageinstantly($img1='',$img2='',$img3=''){
                $x=$y=600;
                header('Content-Type: image/png');
                $targetFolder = '/gw/media/uploads/processed/';
                $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;

                $img1 = $targetPath.'img1.png';
                $img2 = $targetPath.'img2.png';
                $img3 = $targetPath.'img3.png';

                $outputImage = imagecreatetruecolor(600, 600);

                // set background to white
                $white = imagecolorallocate($outputImage, 255, 255, 255);
                imagefill($outputImage, 0, 0, $white);

                $first = imagecreatefrompng($img1);
                $second = imagecreatefrompng($img2);
                $third = imagecreatefrompng($img3);

                //imagecopyresized ( resource $dst_image , resource $src_image , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $dst_w , int $dst_h , int $src_w , int $src_h )
                imagecopyresized($outputImage,$first,0,0,0,0, $x, $y,$x,$y);
                imagecopyresized($outputImage,$second,0,0,0,0, $x, $y,$x,$y);
                imagecopyresized($outputImage,$third,200,200,0,0, 100, 100, 204, 148);

                imagepng($outputImage, $targetPath .round(microtime(true)).'.png');

                imagedestroy($outputImage);
            }
        ?>
```

And the output image
[image]

Comment: I'd recommend to use png with alpha channel instead of jpeg images. Otherwise it would be tricky to achieve the expected result.

Comment: Refer the following link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419383/how-can-i-merge-3-images-into-1-image-via-php Hope this will be useful to you

Comment: Try using `imagecopy()` instead of `imagecopymerge()`

Comment: @MarkSetchell `imagecopy()` has changed the result, still it's not taking whole width

Comment: you either need to scale the image before you copy it or create an image that is not 1000x1000px, but the size of the largest image

Comment: @chillichief, but one cover image is `1000x1000` and i have created the background of `1000x1000`, and it's not completely overlaying being of same size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And i achieved it this way,

Used these 3 images, img1.png,img2.png,img3.png

[image][image][image]

And `create-image.php` file

```
 <?php
        createimageinstantly();
        //$targetFolder = '/gw/media/uploads/processed/';
        //$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
        //$img3 = $targetPath.'img3.png';
        //print_r(getimagesize('http://www.vapor-rage.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/sample.jpg'));
        function createimageinstantly($img1='',$img2='',$img3=''){
            $x=$y=600;
            header('Content-Type: image/png');
            $targetFolder = '/gw/media/uploads/processed/';
            $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;

            $img1 = $targetPath.'img1.png';
            $img2 = $targetPath.'img2.png';
            $img3 = $targetPath.'img3.png';

            $outputImage = imagecreatetruecolor(600, 600);

            // set background to white
            $white = imagecolorallocate($outputImage, 255, 255, 255);
            imagefill($outputImage, 0, 0, $white);

            $first = imagecreatefrompng($img1);
            $second = imagecreatefrompng($img2);
            $third = imagecreatefrompng($img3);

            //imagecopyresized ( resource $dst_image , resource $src_image , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $dst_w , int $dst_h , int $src_w , int $src_h )
            imagecopyresized($outputImage,$first,0,0,0,0, $x, $y,$x,$y);
            imagecopyresized($outputImage,$second,0,0,0,0, $x, $y,$x,$y);
            imagecopyresized($outputImage,$third,200,200,0,0, 100, 100, 204, 148);

            // Add the text
            //imagettftext ( resource $image , float $size , float $angle , int $x , int $y , int $color , string $fontfile , string $text )
            //$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
            $text = 'School Name Here';
            $font = 'OldeEnglish.ttf';
            imagettftext($outputImage, 32, 0, 150, 150, $white, $font, $text);

            $filename =$targetPath .round(microtime(true)).'.png';
            imagepng($outputImage, $filename);

            imagedestroy($outputImage);
        }
    ?>
```

And the result image is 
[image]

Reference : [imagecopyresized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php) & [imagettftext](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php)

thank you for the suggestions made via comments/answers.
And also i blogged this in detail http://sumankc.com/2016/01/30/merge-multiple-images-and-text-to-create-single-image-php-gd-library/
Good day !!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, jpeg images *do not have alpha channel* - it means that every pixel in the image has *some color*, without information about it's transparency. It could be difficult to create a workaround for this, but you could google it. If you can - I advise you to use PNG format, which holds transparency information.

Second of all - try reading the comments section in the [PHP docs for imagecopymerge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php). [This comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php#92787) provides some useful information which you could use:

> *Sina Salek:* I've just checked PHP's issue tracker and a core developer says that
>   this function was never meant to support alpha channel! and they
>   refused to commit the provided patch!

And afterwards the commenter provided an example that I think could work.

Comment: yeah, i actually need to merge png images, that was just testing. 
Now i have used png images and merged those and the result is also updated,